# SpreadsheetDocument.Create() returns URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#, excel, remote-server

I am creating a file (Excel) using C# code to a local server in my organisation.

I keep getting the error "`URI formats are not supported`" when I add "`http`" before the IP of the server. 
If I remove the "`http`" automatically "`C://`" is added which result in path not found error.

Can anybody suggest a way to properly format the URL?

```
  string uriPath = "http:\\1.1.1.1\\Test\\Reports-IdH-ls\\Reports\\tes.xlsx";

  ExportDSToExcel(DatasetItem, uriPath);

  ...
  private void ExportDSToExcel(DataSet ds, string destination)
  {
      using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
      {
          var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
          workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
          workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

          uint sheetId = 1;

          foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
          {
              // fill table ...
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: `string uriPath = @"http:\\1.1.1.1\Test\Reports-IdH-ls\Reports\tes.xlsx";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
string uriPath = "\\\\1.1.1.1\\Test\\Reports-IdH-ls\\Reports\\tes.xlsx";
```

In C#, if you want a backslash, you need to add another backslash to escape it to make it a literal backslash.

Comment: `string uriPath = @"http:\\1.1.1.1\Test\Reports-IdH-ls\Reports\tes.xlsx";` Easier to read!

Comment: @Vlam: Could you please explain, what the problem is and why your suggested solution works. Right now, your "answer" qualifies as comment but not as answer.

Comment: @SirFartALot I have added the explanation.